# Returning a String from an async

Tags: dart, dart-async

I want to return a String from an async function but I get a Future
What am I doing wrong;

Example

```
main() {
  String s;
  s = dummy("http://www.google.com");
}

String dummy(String s) {
  String response;
  response = readURL(s);
  return response;
}


Future<String> readURL(String requestString) async {
  String response = await http.read(requestString);
  print(response);
  return response;

}
```

Error:

> type '_Future' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'response'.

Answer (score 13):

A function that's annotated with `async` will always return a Future.

so when you call `readUrl(s)` you can `await` its result.

To use `await`, the caller (here your main function) has to be marked as `async`. So the end result could look like this:

```
main() async {
  String s = await dummy("http://www.google.com");
}

Future<String> dummy(String s) async {
  String response = await readURL(s);
  return (response);
}

Future<String> readURL(String requestString) async {
  String response = await http.read(requestString);
  print(response);
  return(response);
}
```

The thing to notice here: If you use `await` in a function, it is now considered as function that returns a `Future`. So every function you convert to be `async` will now return a `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **Simple Two way** to get value from Function with return type `Future<Type>`

1- First way (**best way, as you call this code from any file**)

```
FutureFunctionName.then((val) {
      val contains data
    });
```

For example- (**I am posting one from real example**)

```
Future<String> getUserAgents() async {
  String userAgent;
  await FlutterUserAgent.init();
  userAgent = FlutterUserAgent.webViewUserAgent;
  return userAgent;
}
```

```
String userAgent;
getUserAgents().then((val) {
   userAgent = val;
});
print(userAgent); // you will get output
```

2- Second way (use a **global variable to get data**)

```
String userAgent;
Future<void> getUserAgents() async {
  await FlutterUserAgent.init();
  userAgent = FlutterUserAgent.webViewUserAgent;
}
print(userAgent);
```